# how to construct url for image saved in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, knockout.js, linq-to-entities

I am running into a problem. I have my database properly configured and image is saving in database properly but dont know how to construct url for the image saved in database as i have to supply it to the knockout view model for binding.

```
  public JsonResult GetPosts()
    {
        var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = post.Message,
                       PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                       PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
 // having problem at this line dont know how to construct url at this line as i have to supply url
 // (String type to the PostedByAvatar)
                       PostedByAvatar = db.Files.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ApplicationUserId == post.PostedBy),
                       PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                       PostId = post.PostId,
                   }).AsEnumerable();
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is the knockout function--------

```
    function Post(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.PostId = data.PostId;
self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
self.PostedBy = data.PostedBy || "";
self.PostedByName = data.PostedByName || "";

self.PostedDate = getTimeAgo(data.PostedDate);
self.PostedByAvatar = data.PostedByAvatar || "";
self.error = ko.observable();
self.PostComments = ko.observableArray();
```

and this is the view model to get the existing post, comment etc with image from the database-----

```
    function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.loadPosts = function () {
        // to load existing posts
        $.ajax({
            url: postApiUrl1,
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'Get'
        })
```

and on my view page, this the container box to load the image with post-----

```
    <ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <li class="postHolder">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }">
    <p><a data-bind="text: PostedByName"></a>: <span data-bind=" html: Message"></span></p>
```

Now, the model class which saves the image in database is something like this.It has ApplicationUserId as foreign key pointing to ApplicationUserClass---

```
   public class File
   {
    [Key]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
   }
```

and ApplicationUserClass is something like this---

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
   {
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        this.Files = new HashSet<File>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

[image]

This is the image saved in database.Now, i want to know how to construct url for the image saved in the database as i have to supply it to the view model in string form. or there is any approach better than this.

This is my Post class which have many to one relationship with ApplicationUser class and foreign key is PostedBy pointing the ApplicationUser Class----

```
   public class Post
   {
    public Post()
    {
        this.PostComments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int? PostedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to pass a Base64 string as the `src` of the `<img>`, I think the most sensible way would be to not return the actual bytes from the Ajax call but rather create a url that will request the image bytes from the server.

First, add the required Action that will serve the image data:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetFileData(int fileId)
{
    var file = db.Files.Single(x => x.FileId == fileId);

    return File(file.Content, file.ContentType);
}
```

Now, change your `GetPosts` action to return url in the `PostedByAvatar` property:

```
public JsonResult GetPosts()
{
    var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
               orderby post.PostedDate descending)
               select new
               {
                   Message = post.Message,
                   PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                   PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                   PostedByAvatar = _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(post.PostedBy),
                   PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                   PostId = post.PostId,
               });

    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private string _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(int? userId)
{
    if (!user.HasValue)
        return null;

    var avatarImage = db.Files.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ApplicationUserId == userId);

    if (avatarImage != null)
        return Url.Action("GetFileData", new { fileId = avatarImage.FileId });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: many many thnks for replying..as i tried it...it giving me following error message at line item.PostedByAvatar-------- string 'a.PostedByAvatar       Anonymous Types: 'a is new { string Message, int? PostedBy, string PostedByName, string PostedByAvatar, DateTime PostedDate, int PostId}   Error: property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.PostedByAvatar' cannot be assigned to ---it is read only

Comment: sorry, but i have to ask----------in GetPosts  at line-------PostedByAvatar = _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(post.PostedBy), its saying int? Post.PostedBy  Error: The best overload method match for xxx.controller._GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(int)' has some invalid arguments .. I have changed it from UserId to Id as in my database, primary key is Id but still same message

Comment: Show your `Post` class

Comment: i have posted post class in question at the last

Comment: working like charm many many thanks sir , i was stuck in it from the last two week u have saved me sir now, i can relax at least many many thnxx once again sir

Comment: yupp,i am from india now i can enjoy my diwali vacation as this was only troubling me god bless u sir :-)

Comment: hello sir, have a look at it if possible suggest me something ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623147/dynamic-return-type-not-working-but-jsonresult-return-type-working